# prevent jquery from running for small resolutions using bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div block that is shown for larger devices using twitter bootstrap.  This div block has an associated call that retrieve data once the page is ready. I'm trying to avoid making this jquery call when the page is shown on a smaller resolution like a mobile device.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery event looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

           getData();

           function getData() {

               $.post("functions/test_function.php", {f: 'getData'}, function(data) {

                   if (data.success) {   
                       $('#test').html(data.records);
                   }            
               }, "json");
           }
    });

</script>
```

If the page is opened on a smaller devices such that the div is hidden how can I avoid calling my getData function? Do I need to check for the cuurrent resolution via javascript /jquery or does bootstrap have hooks for something like this?

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
if( $('#myDiv:visible').length){
   /* do ajax*/
}
```

Leaves checking size out of equation and lets media queries handle all that

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the div is displayed

```
$("#test").parent("div").css('display') != 'none'
```

If it is displayed, call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) to check for media querys:

```
if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (min-width:950px)"))
```

So fill in your desired breakpoint from where the js part should be executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (min-width:950px)")) {
   getData();
  }

   function getData() {
    $.post("functions/test_function.php", {f: 'getData'}, function(data) {
     if (data.success) {   
      $('#test').html(data.records);
     }            
    }, "json");
   }
});
```